# How to prompt input dialog for entering matrix elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to ask is there any way to let the user to the enter matrix elements (eg. a 3x3 matrix) in a input dialog that has a total 9 boxes in a square manner in matlab. I know matlab got a inputdlg function but the input box will only be in a vertical manner. So I would like to know is there any other option other than using GUI. My concept is like asking the user the matrix size and then I will prompt the corresponding number of boxes for the matrix elements.

Comment: Have you tried the `input` function? What do you mean by "the input box will only be in a vertical manner"?

Comment: I think the OP is alluding to the fact that it's difficult to see exactly what you're doing when entering a large matrix manually on a single line. Your best bet is either: a UI with a [`uitable`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html), or you could create the variable, open the editor using [`openvar`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/openvar.html) and display a message like 'Press ENTER to continue', or you could get the user to enter the matrix one line at a time using `input`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have done it (for solving simultaneus equations), however my problem now is using the data in the matrix I dont think this actually creates a matrix because it wont find the det
`
    clear
    clc

```
prompt={'x:','y:','z:'}
dlg_title='MATRIX A'
num_lines=[1 50]
def={'3','4','8'}
A=inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def)

dlg_title='MATRIX B'
def={'4','3','-3'}
B=inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def)

dlg_title='MATRIX C'
def={'5','-4','-2'}
C=inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def)

D=[A,B,C]'`
```